# Venn diagram with 7 equal regions

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Can you draw 3 overlapping circles (Venn diagram) such that all 7 of the formed regions have the same area?

[image: Venn diagram]

For the case of two circles and 3 equal regions I found this answer:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769136/how-to-create-a-two-circle-venn-diagram-with-3-equal-sections

Comment: My intuition tells me that this isn't possible, but I dunno how to prove it this late at night. Great concept, regardless!

Comment: Well, if you remove the restriction that the 3 areas be *circles*, it's certainly possible. 
 There's no requirement that a Venn diagram be made only of circles, that's just the easiest and classic example.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman While there may be thousands of solutions, it might still be interesting to find a shape that can do that.

Comment: @Strawberry (Irregular) pentagons will do this easily, for example. E.g. let all intersected regions (for 2 or all 3 areas) be equilateral triangles with side 1 (and height $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$), and the remaining areas (belonging to only 1 area) be (isosceles) triangles with base 2 and height $\frac{\sqrt3}{4}$.

Comment: @trolley813 Oh, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Well, that's impossible.

Proof:

> Let $A$ be an area of any of the 7 regions. Now, let us consider only 2 of the overlapping circles (removing 3rd circle for a while) and notice that their overlapping area is $2A$, and each of the non-overlapping parts (belonging to one of the circles, but not both) should also have an area of $2A$. So, the only way to arrange this circles (it will be true for *any pair* of the circles) is as in the linked question (the distance between their centers must be $2x$, where $x\approx0.403972$). So, the centers of the circles must form a right triangle with side $2x$. Plotting this gives the following graph:
>  [image]
>  Now it's clear that the regions have unequal area, even without any calculations (for example, that's because the bottom side of the grey curved triangle, where all 3 circles overlap, lies well below the x-axis, but the intersection points of red and green circles have the same y-coordinates, since their centers lie on the x-axis, so the grey area must be definitely greater then the brown one).
>  Python code for plotting: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNbsMgEIX3nGKkLAwttfzTKMoiqx6jqiLsYBvJNhRwg0/vguukdpQNgvfeN8OMGm0j@3yaRKekttAxq1ppW1HEagw3YAZUa1GlZRfcBpak@dYWIQcnSOL3JD8essM@z47HfXpAqBS6bHnqTc/GH/ML44RCQiikFErZSn2KdESBtaphpyTOyUJlD1QGL@AeyfoZmT@QnnIeDj/FOdnwxZZHlai94JYCZijC7AYT2EEvLYcrh24wFgbDNwka7LWCdoClBlHBKAdo2A8H1gN3wljR1@D7DJoTn/K3pVtdVjgoc3sve4F5ATEXs8vlzLT1MF5WSp7K2XM5/6tiuD27VnQYv6VxRmHeKLyCfxByC4yrwGpr91jIhQHxZ/JFYT4iLSPyr89l71698WZ9VTYkipC4tWdG8dJiPx@at9nIKybT9As) (unfortunately it will not run there, since tio.run does not support external packages, like `matplotlib`).

Comment: Great work! I wasn't sure if this had a solution.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Thanks! I've added a link to Python code used for plotting.

Comment: Got to be honest @DmitryKamenetsky - when I see the OP say "I wasn't sure if this had a solution" it makes me very wary about attempting to solve their future puzzles...

Comment: @Stiv Hmmm... ok I will remember this for my future puzzles and try to make sure they have a solution. For me proving that a puzzle doesn't have a solution is also just as interesting.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I totally agree with you - as a researcher myself a negative finding is often just as useful as (if not more important than) a positive result :) However, in my opinion being 'not sure' if there is a solution to a puzzle is different to *already knowing that there isn't one*. When that's the case it seems to become more of an exercise in mathematical proof and I wonder whether maybe this type of question would be more appropiate on the Math SE rather than Puzzling... Just my opinion! :)

Comment: @Stiv yep got it. No hard feelings.